# How many fields are there between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta_{15}$.I am trying to find the number of $i$ such that:

$\mathbb{Q} \subset L_i \subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})$

Is there a way of using Galois theory to find this?

[Note: Sorry I have not provided much of my own working; I have not managed to find any solutions.]

Comment: In another question you recently asked, you found out what the Galois group of this field is over $\mathbb Q$. What do you know about the relation between the subextensions of your field and the Galois group?

Comment: Just find the subgroups of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})/ \mathbb{Q})\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/(15))^{\times}$. The group has order $\phi(15)=8$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Z_{15}}^*$. Obviously sub extensions will have lower degree than the extension, which in this case is $15$. Will the degrees divide the degree of the original extension by some theorem? This would give $1, 3, 5$ as possible subextensions...

Comment: No, degree $15$ is false. $x^{15}-1$ is not irreducible. And yes, the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group by Lagrange.

Comment: when you say $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq (\mathbb{Z}_{15},\times)$, we know explicitely each automorphisms of that group (not only that it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_{15},\times)$) ? hence we can find explicitly each of its subgroup, and explicitly the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})$ ? that's the main trick of Galois ?

Comment: thanks. @user1952009 when you "we can find explicitly each of its subgroup", could you sketch me through how to do that?

Comment: @Jake so the Galois group is isomorphic to $Z_{15}^*$, order is $\phi(15)=8$... so possible degrees of subgroups are $1, 2, 4$ and $8$. Is it true to say that $1$ and $8$ correspond to to $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})$ respectively... hence there are TWO intermediate subfields?

Answer (score 0):

You really have to look closely at the Galois group, $C_4\oplus C_2$, where I’m using $C_m$ for cyclic group of order $m$. It has three subgroups of order $2$ and three of order $4$. It would steal your fun for me to tell you what they all are.